# Surface Of Revolution First Fundamental Form

Tags: differential-geometry

If I am given a curve 
$$
\beta(\phi)=(cosh\phi,0,\phi)
$$
 How can I find the first fundamental form if I am told that it is a surface of revolution as we know it is of the form:

$$
    \begin{pmatrix} 
    r^2(s)& 0\\
0 &1\end{pmatrix} $$

Or to be more specific how does the form

$$
    \begin{pmatrix} 
    r^2(s)& 0\\
0 &1\end{pmatrix} $$

help us find the first fundamental form of surface of revolution

Answer (score 2):

The general parametrization of a surface of revolution is:
$$(u,\theta)\mapsto(f(u)\cos(\theta),f(u)\sin(\theta),g(u)).$$
Hence, one has:
$$\begin{align}\mathrm{d}x&=f'(u)\cos(\theta)\mathrm{d}u-f(u)\sin(\theta)\mathrm{d}\theta,\\\mathrm{d}y&=f'(u)\sin(\theta)\mathrm{d}u+f(u)\cos(\theta)\mathrm{d}\theta,\\\mathrm{d}z&=g'(u)\mathrm{d}u.\end{align}$$
Finally, one gets:
$$\mathrm{d}s^2:=\mathrm{d}x^2+\mathrm{d}y^2+\mathrm{d}z^2=(f'(u)^2+g'(u)^2)\mathrm{d}u^2+f(u)^2\mathrm{d}\theta^2.$$

**Remark.** If the curve $u\mapsto (f(u),g(u))$ is parametrized at speed one, the first fundamental form is:
$$\mathrm{d}s^2=\mathrm{d}u^2+f(u)^2\mathrm{d}\theta^2.$$